# groupby name and position in the group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to group by a column and then split one or more of the groups into two.

## Exmaple

This

```
np.random.seed(11)
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal":np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 10),
    "number": 1})
df.sort_values("animal")
```

gives me this dataframe

```
   animal  number
1   panda       1
4   panda       1
7   panda       1
9   panda       1
0  python       1
2  python       1
3  python       1
5  python       1
8  python       1
6   shark       1
```

Now I would like to group by animal but also split the "pythons" into the first two and the rest of the "pythons". So that

```
df.grouby(your_magic).sum()
```

gives me

```
        number
animal        
panda        4
python_1     2
python_2     3
shark        1
```

Comment: On what condition do you split `python` into `python_1` and `python_2`?

Comment: @Stefan Just on being the two with the smallest index or not.

Comment: Why is `python` split again but `panda` is not?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that's required by my application. I want to split it up in different ways and compare the results.

Comment: You don't have a logic or condition for splitting a group?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny my condition is if it's the python group I want to split it in to the first two and the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something similar to Stefan's answer but slightly reformulated it to avoid having to use `apply`. This looks a bit cleaner to me.

```
idx1 = df[df['animal'] == 'python'].iloc[:2].index
idx2 = df[df['animal'] == 'python'].iloc[2:].index

df.loc[idx1, "animal"] = "python_1"
df.loc[idx2, "animal"] = "python_2"
df.groupby("animal").sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
np.random.seed(11)
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal":np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 10),
    "number": 1})

## find index on which you split python into python_1 and python_2
python_split_idx = df[df['animal'] == 'python'].iloc[2].name

## rename python according to index
df[df['animal'] == 'python'] = df[df['animal'] == 'python'].apply(lambda row: pd.Series(['python_1' if row.name < python_split_idx else 'python_2', row.number], index=['animal', 'number']), axis=1)

## group according to all animals and sum the number
df.groupby('animal').agg({'number': sum})
```

Output:

```
            number
animal  
panda       4
python_1    2
python_2    3
shark       1
```

Comment: @user2640045 You are welcome. If you are happy with the answer, please accept it such that your question is marked as solved.

Comment: Well I didn't quite like the apply so I posted my own answer based on yours. I will probably accept that one in two days since I can't earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty (and somewhat inefficient) way to do it if you want to rename all your `python`s before you group them.

```py
indices = []

for i,v in enumerate(df['animal']):
        if v == 'python':
            if len(indices) <2:
                indices.append(i)
                df.loc[i,'animal'] = 'python_1'
            else:
                df.loc[i,'animal'] = 'python_2'
        

grouped = df.groupby('animal').agg('sum')
print(grouped)
```

This provides your desired output exactly.

As an alternative, here's a totally different approach that creates another column to capture whether each animal is a member of the group of the top two pythons and then groups on both columns.

```py
snakes = df[df['animal'] == 'python']
df['special_snakes'] = [1 if i not in snakes.index[:2] else 0 for i in df.index]
df.groupby(['animal', 'special_snakes']).agg('sum')
```

The output looks a bit different, but achieves the same outcome. This approach also has the advantage of capturing the condition on which you are grouping your animals without actually changing the values in the `animal` column.

```
                       number
animal special_snakes        
panda  1                    4
python 0                    2
       1                    3
shark  1                    1
```